# Very Strange error when trying to INSERT into a database with more than 1 entry

Tags: mysql, sql

HOPEFULLY.....the title makes sense. But basically this is what is going on. I'm creating a form where a user will be able to View, Update, Insert and Delete records from tables within a database.

I'm using a combo box to display the table data:

Now If I try to Insert a new record, it works fine, until I try and more than one.

This is me placing just the personID record in. and it works fine:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/E2oHlXy.png]

But if i try and add a personID AND a firstName this happens:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aPpIvNh.png]

as you can see, it ignores the personID entry, and just goes for the firstName.

I cant go further in my code without figuring out what is causing me to not be able to put in 2 things at once.

Here is my INSERT code:

```
string myInsertSQL;
        myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";
        myInsertSQL += "personID)";
        myInsertSQL += " VALUES ('";
        myInsertSQL += personID.Text + "')";
        myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";
        myInsertSQL += "firstName)";
        myInsertSQL += " VALUES ('";
        myInsertSQL += firstName.Text + "')";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myInsertSQL, conn);
```

With the above, it will only insert the firstName.

I have no idea why this would happen, and I would love some input. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you are wide open to accidental mistakes and deliberate SQL injection. Use bound parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing this, the DB would insert the ID and the firstname on 2 distinct rows, if you didn't overwrite the first string (`myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";`). Here, it only performs the second query (i.e. inserting first name).

Try:

```csharp
    myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";
    myInsertSQL += "personID, FirstName)";
    myInsertSQL += " VALUES ('";
    myInsertSQL += personID.Text + "', '"+ firstName.Text +"')";
```

Please note that this is wide open to SQL injections. Try to use prepared statements instead of directly injecting plain text into queries:

```csharp
string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personID, firstName) VALUES (@personID, @firstName)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myInsertSQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName.Text);
```

**EDIT** :

According to your comment, you try to insert more than those 2 values. This work the same.

The error says that you did specify a different number of values and fields. You speak of 6 values, but only list 5 (personID, firstName, address, phoneNumber, postCode). I suspect you forgot the lastName:

```csharp
string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personID, lastName, firstName, address, phoneNumber, postCode) ";
myInsertSQL += "VALUES (@personID, @lastName, @firstName, @address, @phoneNumber, @postCode)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myInsertSQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode.Text);
// and so on...
```

Comment: EDIT: Worked When I just tried with 2, personID and firstName, but now that I sued all 6 entries, address, phoneNumber, postCode. it gives a "Error inserting recordColum count doesn't match value count at row1"

Comment: EDIT 2: Yeah sorry I forgot last name, with the new code however, it is giving me the SAME error as before, where even though i placed a personID entry (the number 5) it gave me an error "Duplicate entry for primary key 0" and that is the same thing that happened before, when it skipped personID and went to the next entry.

Comment: Because after all your tries, your table already contains this ID. Just delete the relevant rows and try again. Or if your table was empty when you started, just `TRUNCATE` it.

Comment: I dont have personID 5 in my database, I will delete the rows and try again just in case.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table ? As it says "primary key 0", is there another column in your table used as a primary key that defaults to 0 ? If yes, you have to add a value to the primary key in each of your insert queries.

Comment: OOOOOK. So now I have a VERRY strange error. I deleted all rows except the 2 original ones. I tried inserting a new record and this was inserted into the table: 0,@firstName,@lastName,@address,0,0

Comment: Hmmm :/ Well I'l continue to work on this, but I will give you a "correct answer" because you did help with the initial problem

Answer (score 2):

```
myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";
```

here you completely overwrite the myInsertSQL String, so whatever you put in there before is gone before you even send it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting variable value

```
    myInsertSQL += personID.Text + "')";
    myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(";
```